# Get the whole ROW which has the MAX value for a column with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have exhausted my wit with this problem, so I bring the challenge to you:

```
--CREATING DATA:

DECLARE @CONTACTS TABLE (ID INT, NickName CHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @CONTACTS VALUES (1359,'John Smith')
INSERT INTO @CONTACTS VALUES (1360,'Ana Keller')
INSERT INTO @CONTACTS VALUES (1361,'Joshua Doe')

DECLARE @ENTERPRISES TABLE (ID INT, CON_ID INT, ASSOCIATION DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @ENTERPRISES VALUES (123,1359,Convert(datetime, '2000-10-09', 120))
INSERT INTO @ENTERPRISES VALUES (123,1360,Convert(datetime, '2000-02-21', 120))
INSERT INTO @ENTERPRISES VALUES (123,1361,Convert(datetime, '2000-04-09', 120))

--QUERYING THE DATA:
SELECT * FROM @CONTACTS C
JOIN @ENTERPRISES E ON C.ID = E.CON_ID

--THE RESULT SET OF MY DREAMS:
    1359    John Smith    123    1359    2000-10-09
```

What I want is an entire row of the query before, but only the one that has the maximum ASSOCIATION date for each Enterprise ID. This is only an example for the sake of clarity, my real query is much more complex, with much more columns and trillions of rows. I have tried

```
SELECT *,max(FOUNDING) OVER (PARTITION BY E.ID) FROM @CONTACTS C
JOIN @ENTERPRISES E ON C.ID = E.CON_ID
```

But it still brings all three rows. Other approaches were worse and led to the parser asking me to GROUP BY every column. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cteMaxAssociation AS (
    SELECT ID, CON_ID, ASSOCIATION,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ASSOCIATION DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM @ENTERPRISES
)
SELECT C.ID, C.NickName, ma.ID, ma.CON_ID, ma.ASSOCIATION
    FROM @CONTACTS C
        INNER JOIN cteMaxAssociation ma
            ON C.ID = ma.CON_ID
                AND ma.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: works on the example, but in my (supposedly analog query) I get a pretty "Column ASSOCIATION is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.". The parser wants me to group association...

Comment: @Lynx: There is no `GROUP BY` clause in the query I gave you. I'm not a mind reader. If you want me to diagnose a different query, you'll have to edit your question and add it in so I can see it.

Comment: I appreciate your sense of humour. "DT_CAD_CLI" is the analog to the "ASSOCIATION" in the example, the column for which I want only the bigger value over each C1.ID_CLI.

Comment: @Lynx: I think we got our wires crossed here. What I wanted to see was your implementation of my query.

Comment: You just got me started in an Idea that solved the problem, I used ORDER BY with ROW_NUMBER() to remove the GROUP BY from my query and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM  @CONTACTS C
JOIN @ENTERPRISES E ON C.ID = E.CON_ID 
   (SELECT max(association) as maxdate, CON_ID , ID, ASSOCIATION 
     FROM Entpresises
     GROUP BY CON_ID ) maxresults
WHERE E.ID = maxresults.ID
AND E.ASSOCIATION = maxresults.ASSOCIATION ;
```

Comment: Regarding your `maxresults` subquery: 1. OP is asking for maximum `ASSOCIATION` per `ID`, not by `CON_ID`. 2. You need to `GROUP BY` all the non-aggregate columns: `CON_ID, ID` 3. You can't include `ASSOCIATION` as a column and simultaneously compute the `MAX(ASSOCIATION)`

Comment: You're right, I just constructed the query on the fly without even revision :)